# How to handle scipy minimize ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, valueerror

```
I am trying to minimize the following function by use of the scipy library:
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def constraint1(bet):
    a,b = bet
    return 100 - a + b

con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons = [con1]
b0, b1 = (0,100), (0,100)   
bnds = (b0, b1)

def f(bet, sign = -1, *args):
    d0, d1, p0, p1 = args
    a,b = bet
    wins0 = a * (d0-1)
    wins1 = b * (d1-1)
    loss0 = b
    loss1 = a
    log0 = np.log(bank + wins0 - loss0)
    log1 = np.log(bank + wins1 - loss1)
    
    objective = (log0 * p0 + log1 * p1)
    return sign * objective

bet = [0,0]
minimize(f, bet, args = (1,2,3,4,), method = 'trust-constr', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
```

This however results in a `ValueError:`

```
 d0, d1, p0, p1 = args (Think this is where the error occurs)
 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

Tried leaving out the `,` so it looks like this :`(1,2,3,4)` , but that didn't work either.

Anything would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `minimize` function with optional arguments. The function has to look like this:

```
fun(x, *args)
```

There is no place for an optional argument. So what you want to do is to call your function explicitly providing `-1` as one of `args`:

```
minimize(f, bet, args = (-1, 1, 2, 3, 4,),method = 'trust-constr',
         bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
```

Here is the link to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).